# R leaflet : event when click outside a polygon

Tags: r, leaflet

I built a leaflet map and I wonder if it's possible to set the "input$mymap_shape_click$id" to NULL when I click outside a polygon ?

Because, a conditionalPanel appears when I click in a polygon and I would like it to close when I click in the sea for example.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In the same way that you can [click on a shape](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41711559/5977215), you can also observe the click on the map: `observeEvent(input$mymap_click, { print("map clicked") })`. And working with through the same logic as in the linked answer, you can store 'click' events in a `reactiveValue()`, and respond when they change

Comment: It seems that you're my saver today, thank you very much. Would you know where I can find some details about these two commands ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I found them by going through [the source code](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/ab565412ee53e736ba69c883c66856cacf9d3ed7/inst/htmlwidgets/leaflet.js)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do the same, thank you very much again SymbolixAU.

Comment: if you search that page for `_click`, you'll find all the elements that take a `click` event

Comment: Ok, I will take a look to that page, because my conditionalPanel doesn't want to close, lol. Thanks a lot SymbolixAU.

Comment: I couldn't find any event for 'click outside all polygons' so I just used `mapname_click` instead of `mapname_shape_click` and manually checked in the server code if the click was within a polygon or outside my shapefile (using `st_within`).